# Commenting build results on a PR from a forked repo with GitHub actions

Tags: github, build, github-actions, pull-request, prettier

I want to run a [prettier](https://prettier.io/) check on the PRs before being able to merge them, and case it fails I want to display an HTML diff of the changes needed to be made so that it passes the prettier check. **Almost all PRs are created from forks of the repo**. I am using [thollander/actions-comment-pull-request](https://github.com/thollander/actions-comment-pull-request?tab=readme-ov-file#permissions) GitHub action to do the actual comment on the PRs. In its docs, it states:

> Note that, if the PR comes from a fork, it will have only read permission despite the permissions given in the action for the `pull_request` event. In this case, you may use the `pull_request_target` event. With this event, permissions can be given without issue (the difference is that it will execute the action from the target branch and not from the origin PR).

But as I read it [GitHub itself doesn't recommend](https://securitylab.github.com/research/github-actions-preventing-pwn-requests/) using `pull_request_target` since it could open up security breaches. In this same post they recommend splitting up the build action from the commenting one. But how can I create a GitHub action that only runs when another workflow fails AND with the permissions needed as `pull_request_target` so I could comment on the PR?

My current solution is composed of 2 workflows:

The first one that runs a prettier check on PR and if it fails uploads an artifact that is an HTML diff of the changes needed to be made to pass prettier check. It also triggers a dispatch event to pass information to the second workflow.

```yaml
name: Prettier code formatter

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
      - main
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - main

jobs:
  check:
    # available images: https://github.com/actions/runner-images#available-images
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout ️
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Setup Node.js ⚙️
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
      - name: Install Prettier 
        run: npm install --save-dev --save-exact prettier @shopify/prettier-plugin-liquid
      - name: Prettier Check 
        id: prettier
        run: npx prettier . --check
      - name: Create diff 
        # https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#failure
        if: ${{ failure() }}
        run: |
          npx prettier . --write
          git diff -- . ':(exclude)package-lock.json' ':(exclude)package.json' > diff.txt
          npm install -g diff2html-cli
          diff2html -i file -s side -F diff.html -- diff.txt
      - name: Upload html diff ⬆️
        id: artifact-upload
        if: ${{ failure() && steps.prettier.conclusion == 'failure' }}
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: HTML Diff
          path: diff.html
          retention-days: 7
      - name: Dispatch information to repository ️
        if: ${{ failure() && steps.prettier.conclusion == 'failure' && github.event_name == 'pull_request' }}
        uses: peter-evans/repository-dispatch@v2
        with:
          event-type: prettier-failed-on-pr
          client-payload: '{"pr_number": "${{ github.event.number }}", "artifact_url": "${{ steps.artifact-upload.outputs.artifact-url }}", "run_id": "${{ github.run_id }}"}'
```

The second one that gets information from the failed run, like `pr_number`, `artifact_url`, and `run_id`, and comments on the `pr_number` PR with the link to the failed run and the artifact with the HTML diff to be accessed.

```yaml
name: Comment on pull request

on:
  repository_dispatch:
    types: [prettier-failed-on-pr]

jobs:
  comment:
    # available images: https://github.com/actions/runner-images#available-images
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: PR comment with html diff 
        uses: thollander/actions-comment-pull-request@v2
        with:
          comment_tag: prettier-failed
          pr_number: ${{ github.event.client_payload.pr_number }}
          message: |
            Failed [prettier code check](${{ github.server_url }}/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs/${{ github.event.client_payload.run_id }}). Check [this file](${{ github.event.client_payload.artifact_url }}) for more information.
```

So, how can I make the second workflow run with the permissions needed as `pull_request_target` so I could comment on the PR?